# Extracting Offline MAC Address

Tags: excel, macos, vba

I'm currently making an Excel sheet that extracting MAC Address. I managed to extract Connected/Online MAC address by using the following code:

```
Dim objVMI As Object
Dim vAdptr As Variant
Dim objAdptr As Object
Dim adptrCnt As Long


Set objVMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
Set vAdptr = objVMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")
For Each objAdptr In vAdptr
If Not IsNull(objAdptr.MACAddress) And IsArray(objAdptr.IPAddress) Then
For adptrCnt = 0 To UBound(objAdptr.IPAddress)
If Not objAdptr.IPAddress(adptrCnt) = "0.0.0.0" Then
GetNetworkConnectionMACAddress = objAdptr.MACAddress
Exit For
End If
Next adptrCnt
End If
Next

Range("A1").Value = GetNetworkConnectionMACAddress
```

However, this code only extract the connected MAC. May I know how extract the offline MAC Address?

Comment: Are you asking to get all MAC addresses for all the available adapters on your machine, regardless if they have a connection or not? .. If so, what results are returned when you take off your `WHERE` clause (`WHERE IPEnabled = True`)?

Comment: Well, yea. i prefer it extract all the MAC Address regardless if have a connection or not. Then from there i choose the first MAC address for my code.

I removed the where clause but still the result is same where it only return the connected MAC address

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Function getMacAddress()
'== function to get MAC adress (all)
Dim objVMI As Object, vAdptr As Variant
Dim objAdptr As Object
Dim strMacAdr As String, i As Long
      getMacAddress = vbNullString
      Set objVMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\cimv2")
'== get the using MAC address with IP
      Set vAdptr = objVMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")
      For Each objAdptr In vAdptr
            If IsNull(objAdptr.MACAddress) Then GoTo ff
            strMacAdr = Trim(objAdptr.MACAddress)
            If Not IsArray(objAdptr.IPAddress) Then GoTo ff
             For i = 0 To UBound(objAdptr.IPAddress)
                  If Not Trim(objAdptr.IPAddress(i)) = "0.0.0.0" Then getMacAddress = getMacAddress & vbCrLf & strMacAdr & " (" & Trim(objAdptr.IPAddress(i)) & ")"
            Next
ff:
      Next
'== get all MAC address
      Set vAdptr = objVMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE MACAddress IS NOT NULL")
      For Each objAdptr In vAdptr
            If Not IsNull(objAdptr.MACAddress) Then
                  strMacAdr = Trim(objAdptr.MACAddress)
                  If InStrRev(getMacAddress, strMacAdr) = 0 Then getMacAddress = getMacAddress & vbCrLf & Trim(objAdptr.MACAddress)
            End If
      Next
      Set objVMI = Nothing
      Set vAdptr = Nothing
      Set objAdptr = Nothing
      MsgBox getMacAddress
End Function
```